# How do you fill the image within other image's boundaries?

Tags: css

Hi guys i am trying to fill an image inside a png outline like this

[image]

Currently what i have

```html
<img _ngcontent-udx-c1="" alt="content-icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob90p.png" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background: url(&quot;https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/nature-quotes-1557340276.jpg&quot;);">
```

where the event-icon.png is the white outline and the background is some random image from google. And the result is
[image]

But i want it do fill inside the other image's boundaries instead of just pushing it out through the entire tag. How can i achieve this?

Comment: share the PNG  image

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://imgur.com/ZTXg31t

Comment: You'd need a clip-path to do that.

Comment: You can paint the parts of `event-icon.png` where you want the image to appear white and then use [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another image like below and use it as mask:

```css
body {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/RyJRkpB/mask.png" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob90p.png" />
```

In the above we have both images, the mask and the one with outline and you get the following if you combine them:

```css
.box {
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/RyJRkpB/mask.png) center/contain no-repeat;
          mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/RyJRkpB/mask.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1014/800/800) center/cover;
}

body {
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob90p.png" class="box">
```

The result isn't perfect because I am bad at image editing but you can easily edit the mask image to make it better